# Reduce display brightness to zero in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: display, brightness

I recently tried to use xfce4-session on a standard ubuntu 18.10 machine, and was pleasantly surprised that I could reduce the display brightness to zero (by pressing Fn+F11 on a laptop repeatedly). In a gnome session this is not possible, you can reduce it to a certain degree but no more.

In both DEs, XDG_SESSION_TYPE is x11.

Any one knows why this happens and how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

try

`xrandr --output $(xrandr --current | grep ' connected' | awk '{print $1}') --brightness 0.05`

You can use any setting, including 0, but zero will make your screen go completely black so I put 0.05 into the test command so you can still see your screen somewhat and increase the brightness back to normal.

And if you would like to have it as a brightness decreasing script you can use:

`xrandr --output $(xrandr --current | grep ' connected' | awk ' {print $1} ') --brightness  $(xrandr --verbose | grep Bright | awk ' { print ($2 - 0.05)}')`

and increasing:

`xrandr --output $(xrandr --current | grep ' connected' | awk ' {print $1} ') --brightness  $(xrandr --verbose | grep Bright | awk ' { print ($2 + 0.05)}')`